# How to prevent others accessing links restricted for admin users only

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using the jstl code to hide buttons that must be the only admin user to access...Now for example I hide the button to the ordinary user which redirects to deletepage.jsp. I made it corrrecly using the c:if jstl tag...But it will still be accessed by the ordinary user if they know the links...How to prevent this situation?

Comment: You need [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service). Click on above link for more information

Comment: You may want to configure web security, "URL patters" may provide what u looking for.. Refer Here for detailed tutorial on web security.. http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security

Comment: The answer depends on how you're managing the logged-in user and its roles. Are you using container managed authentication or did you homebrew something?

Comment: Agreed with @BalusC sir .

Comment: What do you mean by homebrew? I am assigning every user a role then hide specific controls for non admin users

Comment: Homebrew == self-written Java code to accomplish the requirement. So, once again, are you using container managed authentication (which is just a simple `<security-constraint>` configuration entry in `web.xml`) or have you homebrewed/written/reinvented all the Java code yourself (e.g. using a servlet filter for URL restriction and a servlet for login)? If you have homebrewed all the code yourself, then you'd need to show how exactly how you've identified and stored the logged-in user. Did you store it as a session attribute? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using MVC, you could have the controller check the user's identity against an Access Control List (ACL) to prevent access to the restricted pages. Also, to seal this even further, you could have an extra check for direct access to those restricted pages so that users cannot request them directly. The implementation specifics for this suggested solution are for you to decide on depending on your design.

Comment: URL based access restriction isn't the responsibility of a MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1015950) in the web.xml file and then implement the SecurityFilter class. In this class, you need to implement the function

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
}
```

and then, you can check whether there is a session of the current user for the requested url. If yes, then you can navigate him to the page; otherwise, just deny and redirect to the error page

```
if ("/admin.jsp".equals(httpReq.getServletPath())) {
    if(httpReq.getSession().getAttribute("CurrentUser")!=null) {

        // go to the requested url 
    }
    else {
        httpReq.getRequestDispatcher("/no_access.jsp").forward(httpReq, httpRes);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

3 ways of doing this:

1-Do validation on every servlet handling calls with this problem.
2- Do it by filters.
3- Use any framework like struts.

Framework will cause less code to write and in appropriate way. If you don't want framework,which is preffered, you should use filters